# Yocto native build of some recipes for 32 bit on 64bit system

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am trying to build some native packages as 32bit in yocto (2.6.1 actually, on a 64bit linux). My target does not use multilib at all. Let's say I am building recipe `a` which needs (all build-time, linking statically) package `b` as well as  `zlib` and `libcrypto`. I manage to build a and b as 32bit by simply adding `-m32` to the gcc calls, and linking/running works fine. However, the build system does not know about it and puts everything under `work/x86_64-linux`.

I have to use pre-build 32bit zlib and libcrypto libraries for this to work because yocto will of course try to give me the 64bit versions of zlib and libcrypto when I let it (`DEPENDS_class-native = "b-native zlib-native openssl-native"`), resulting in a linker error. It would be nice to have yocto build them for me in the correct architecture.

I have experimented with `TARGET_ARCH` and `BUILD_ARCH` but it either does not change it to 32bit at all, or it gives an error that it does not find e.g. `quilt`  as 32bit (to apply patches, which could/should be done using 64bit quilt).

The specific errors are prepended by a lot of

```
WARNING: a-native-1_0.4-r0 do_prepare_recipe_sysroot: 
Manifest /yoctoroot/work/sstate-control/manifest-i586-quilt-native.populate_sysroot 
not found in i586 (variant '')?
....
WARNING: a-native-1_0.4-r0 do_prepare_recipe_sysroot: 
Manifest /yoctoroot/work/sstate-control/manifest-i586-openssl-native.populate_sysroot 
not found in i586 (variant '')?
....
ERROR: a-native-1_0.4-r0 do_patch: 
Command Error: 'quilt --quiltrc /yoctoroot/work/i586-linux/a-native/1_0.4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/etc/quiltrc push' 
exited with 0  Output:    /bin/sh: quilt: command not found
ERROR: a-native-1_0.4-r0 do_patch: Function failed: patch_do_patch
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: ...
```

when I add

```
BUILD_ARCH_native = "i586"
BUILD_ARCH_class-native = "i586"
TARGET_ARCH_native = "x86"
TARGET_ARCH_class-native = "x86"
```

to the a and b recpies.

The packages a and b are not native-only, they are also built for the target and use `BBCLASSEXTEND = "native"` to enable native builds; a solution should ideally not break the target builds and not all other native stuff in the ecosystem.

The reason why I want them 32bit at all is that the packages a and b do intermixed pointer/integer arithmetic which breaks when the sizes of these datatypes do not match; I would appreciate if I would not have to change these sources. Am I asking too much?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts and directions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it going, but it does not feel much better than using pre-built binaries and seems not feasible if there were more than just two dependencies.

I added the following lines to the a and b recipes (well, the BBCLASSEXTEND was already there):

```
BUILD_ARCH_class-native = "i586"
TARGET_ARCH_class-native = "x86"
PATCHTOOL_class-native = "patch"
BBCLASSEXTEND = "native"
```

This makes the quilt error go away and puts them in the `i586-linux` directory instead of `x86_64-linux`.

For zlib and openssl, I copied the original recipes into one of my own layers (including patch files etc.) as `zlib32bitxyz-native` and `openssl32bitxyz-native`, added these lines:

```
BUILD_ARCH = "i586"
TARGET_ARCH = "x86"
PATCHTOOL = "patch"
inherit native
BP = "openssl-${PV}" # or zlib
```

as well as replacing `${PN}` by `openssl` and `zlib` respectively at some places.

Making them build 32bit was a nop for openssl, it simply worked.

For zlib, things started with not finding an `xz` to unpack the downloaded archive. I added a link to my `/usr/bin/xz` in the hosttools directory manually.

Additionally, I tweaked

```
do_configure() {
    CFLAGS="-m32" ./configure --prefix=${WORKDIR}/recipe-sysroot-native/usr --libdir=${WORKDIR}/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib --uname=GNU
}
```

which makes the build 32bit and removes the build of unused shared stuff.

Then, in recipe a, the native depends now reads

```
DEPENDS_class-native += "b-native openssl32bitxyz-native zlib32bitxyz-native"
```

and all builds and links okay (but with a lot of warnings, see question) and comes out 32bit.

If this gives you a shudder, feel free to guide me the correct way.

**Edit: What does not work**

One night, I thought, why not simply use `zlib_%.bbappend` and `openssl_%.bbappend` in my layers containing simply only

```
BUILD_ARCH_class-native = "i586"
TARGET_ARCH_class-native = "x86"
PATCHTOOL_class-native = "patch"
BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

plus, for zlib, the `do_configure_class-native` as above, and then replace in recipe `a`
    DEPENDS_class-native += "b-native zlib-native openssl-native"

For `a` this does work!! However, it breaks **nearly** everything else native, e.g. the `do_configure` from `kmod_native` by

```
| checking for zlib... no
| configure: error: Package requirements (zlib) were not met:
| 
| No package 'zlib' found
| 
| Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
| installed software in a non-standard prefix.
| 
| Alternatively, you may set the environment variables zlib_CFLAGS
| and zlib_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
| See the pkg-config man page for more details.
| NOTE: The following config.log files may provide further information.
| NOTE: /media/hegny/1.42.6-5592/yo419/tisdk_workdir-external-arm-toolchain/work/x86_64-linux/kmod-native/25+gitAUTOINC+aca4eca103-r0/build/config.log
| ERROR: configure failed
| WARNING: /media/hegny/1.42.6-5592/yo419/tisdk_workdir-external-arm-toolchain/work/x86_64-linux/kmod-native/25+gitAUTOINC+aca4eca103-r0/temp/run.do_configure.28023:1 exit 1 from 'exit 1'
| ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /media/hegny/1.42.6-5592/yo419/tisdk_workdir-external-arm-toolchain/work/x86_64-linux/kmod-native/25+gitAUTOINC+aca4eca103-r0/temp/log.do_configure.28023)
ERROR: Task (/media/hegny/1.42.6-5592/yo419/tisdk/sources/oe-core/meta/recipes-kernel/kmod/kmod-native_git.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
```

**Ain't there anyhing like a native multilib which is simple?**